# Why do I have SwiftUITests and SwiftUIUI folders in my Xcode project?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I reinstalled my Xcode and created a new project then I saw there were two folders generated within project folder, I never saw it in my previous project folder. So how can I create a project without those folders? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Unit testings and UI testing have different targets (giving different concept of testing), so have different folders generated from templates.

Answer (score 1):

You have to uncheck the check_box appearing in front of "`Include Tests`" while you are creating new project and asked to "`Choose options for your new project`".

Check the image attached:-
[Remove Tests from project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c08yg.png)